# Would it be preferable to use "Dear Sir/Madam," rather than "Dear," to start an e-mail?

Tags: email, greetings

Are there specific cases where "Dear Sir/Madam," would be better then simpler "Dear," to start an e-mail?

To give more context, I am preparing an e-mail to ask about eligibility for a certain job offer. The e-mails address is one of those generic (like questions@example.com).

Comment: Never start an e-mail with a simple "Dear," -- it looks too much like a scam/phishing bait.

Comment: What does your job seeker manual tell you about such a situation?

Comment: So, "Dear Sir/Madam," is the standard approach? May I ask for more appropriate alternatives?

Comment: Much better than "Dear," -- at least in my book.  If you know the name of the person, it would be even better.  It might not be a bad idea to give them a call and ask the name of the HR person in charge of job advertisements, and how to contact them.  What do you got to lose?

Comment: You can use "Hi" or "Hello" if you want to be a bit less formal. Depends on the job/area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not on subject line but inside the e-mail I'd use “Dear Sir/Madam” rather than just “Dear.” If you just write "Dear" it makes it sound like a love letter.

Comment: In graduate school the prof got a freshman student on a work-study program as a secretary. She closed a couple of business letters "Love," and he flipped. ;-)